# Loader Flickering Not Rendering WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to run a long process to retrieve data and show loader screen (simple form) as a dialog while the data is being retrieved. The issue I'm having is while the background worker is running, the loader screen just flickers and doesn't render the labels in the loader form. You can see just the gray rectangles while the background working is running as shown below.

[image]

Does anyone know why the loader form is not showing their labels and why it is flickering?

```
private void LoadInfo()
{
    try
    {
        workingLoader = new WorkingLoader();
        mainWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        mainWorker.DoWork += MainWorker_DoWork;
        mainWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += MainWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

        mainWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        workingLoader.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (workingLoader != null)
        {
            workingLoader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe call Update() on workingLoader on load ? or move the mainWorker to workingLoader form?

Comment: Where and how are the Labels being updated?

Comment: The labels are static - it basically says loading

Comment: Have you tried setting `DoubleBuffered` to `true`?

Comment: I don't see you subscribing to [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress)? Are you trying to update those controls from `DoWork`? Maybe, also in a close loop using `.Invoke()`? How can `mainWorker` update controls in `workingLoader`, which is shown as Modal?

Comment: No luck on DoubleBuffered. Not showing progress, just showing a modal dialog while background worker is running.

Comment: It would greatly help if you could provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: we dont see your code that updates any labels, so how could we possible help ?

Comment: The labels are static, all I'm doing is showing a popup form that says "Loading - Please Wait". The popup form has a few Labels, it doesn't report on progress or anything. The background worker is fetching data and takes a bit of time and the popup form just flickers and doesn't show the label text. It's showing the image presented.

Comment: So, you have no code at all inside that Form (`workingLoader`)? Anything that `loops`?

Comment: Correct, no code at all in there.

Comment: You know that this is simply not possible, right? If what you're presenting here is your actual code, I mean. Even if you put `Thread.Sleep(100000)` in `DoWork`, the modal Form would show correctly: it runs in another thread. You're not showing all there is to show.

Answer (score -1):

```
internal static class NativeWinAPI
{
internal static readonly int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
internal static readonly int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
}

And your form constructor should look as follows:


public MyForm()
{
InitializeComponent();

int style = NativeWinAPI.GetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE);
style |= NativeWinAPI.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
NativeWinAPI.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
}

In the code above, you might change this.Handle to something like MyFlickeringPanel.Handle
```